# Laravel File Upload or jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am a beginner with Laravel and am currently working on a fun project - a media sharing site. The question I have is whether I should utilize the Laravel `store()` method or if it is more beneficial to use jQuery-File-Upload?

I am planning on being able to upload multiple large files as well. I would like to hear the pros and cons, as I cannot find much information on the Laravel upload functions. Thanks!

Comment: I would go for laravel, it's can hold big size data and it's flexible when you upload to s3,ec2 or any other cloud service. jQuery on the other hand sometimes faces issue for file-controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about 2 different scripts. Client-side (jQuery / Javascript) and server side (Laravel / PHP).

You can use jQuery file upload to upload the file to the server (via AJAX), and Laravel (PHP) will take care of saving the file to the server.

My suggestion is master the basics first before diving into any frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Laravel. Laravel has it’s own functions to make files upload easy and fast. Even validating your uploaded files in Laravel is very easy.

You can still use jQuery to post the files to the controller, this way the user won't see a page refresh.